# Local variable not becoming global

Tags: javascript, ros

I am writing a program to get values from a flight controller and then use those values to interact with a HUD. The problem I'm facing is I can't get the variable from inside the flight controller function and pass it to the HUD function. I've tried `window` with no luck, tried nesting the functions, and other stuff I've found online - none of it works. Any help would be really appreciated. Here's the code -

This is the part that pulls the data from the flight controller -

```
var roll_in;
listenerImu.subscribe(function(message, roll_in) {
    roll_in = (message.twist.linear.x) * (-57.2958);
    return roll_in;
});
```

Once the data is put into `roll_in`, it needs to be put into this function -

```
function FlightIndicator(placeholder, type, options) {
    var attitude = this;
    var settings = $.extend({
        size: 500,
        roll: roll_in, // Vehicle Roll
        pitch: pitch_in, // Vehicle Pitch
        turn: 0,
        heading: 0,
        vario: 0,
        airspeed: 0,
        altitude: 0,
        pressure: 1000,
        showBox: false,
        img_directory: 'jQuery-Flight-Indicators-master/img/'
    },
    options);
}
```

Even if I put a `console.print(roll_in)` right after the `listenerImu` function, it prints `undefined`.

Thanks!

Comment: because you define roll_in in a block scope. That return does nothing also

Comment: He said that he tried `window.roll_in`.
We may need the full file where `roll_in` is declare and where this script is execute ? in a browser ?

Comment: Note: [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: Note, that arguments get their value when a function is called, not when it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You redefine the variable in block scope when you declared it as an argument in the function.

```
var roll_in;  //global
listenerImu.subscribe(function(message, roll_in) {  //creates a new variable here in this block scope
    roll_in = (message.twist.linear.x) * (-57.2958);  //uses the argument, not global
    return roll_in;  //this line appears to do nothing
});
```

Your code should just be this

```
var roll_in; 
listenerImu.subscribe(function(message) {  
    roll_in = (message.twist.linear.x) * (-57.2958);
});
```

Now next issue is `subscribe` is going to be an asynchronous call so the variable `roll_in` will be undefined until that line is triggered. Adding any console.log() lines after it will still show undefined. It is like ordering a pizza online, you can not eat it until it shows up at your house.

Comment: Alright, I switched it to what you suggested. Now when I run the program, I'm getting an error saying that roll_in is not defined on this line`roll : roll_in`. Do I have to pass the variable into the `function FlightIndicator` function somehow? I know that the variable is constantly updating, I can see the info being passed into roll_in

Comment: It is the pizza delivery issue. You are trying to read the value before it is returned. You need to call your `FlightIndicator` method after the value comes back in subscribe.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. What would you use to call it? Put the whole `FlightIndicator` function inside there? Thanks again for your help epascarello.

Comment: just call it when you set the value

Answer (score 0):

```
    var roll_in;
    listenerImu.subscribe(function(message, roll_in) {
        roll_in = (message.twist.linear.x) * (-57.2958);
           ^ This is the parameter roll_in
```

Just change the `roll_in` param to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variable to be assigned to the outer scope roll_in, don't pass it as an argument to the subscribe callback.

```
var roll_in;
listenerImu.subscribe(function(message) {
    roll_in = (message.twist.linear.x) * (-57.2958);
});
```

When roll_in is used as an argument in the callback, any assigned inside that callback will affect the argument variable, having no affect on the outer scope's roll_in.